# Beginners question in dealing with drawables for Samsung Galaxy tab

Tags: android, resources, android-3.0-honeycomb

In a curious to code my first app for Samsung tablet I got struck without knowing how to deal in naming drawable folders, I am using Android 3.0 ,to start with, I browsed through websites to learn its specification, i found Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 is of 7-inch display screen with 2048×1200 pixel resolution running on android 3.0 and other site pointed to Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 runs on same android 3.0 with resolution of 1280 x 800 pixels and 10.10 size ,My fist question, do Samsung have 2 different models running on same version of android ,Second  question is that if i need my app to run on this both tablet where should i place the images when my supports-screens tag points to android:anyDensity="true", what could be the layout and drawables, i need my app to run in tablets that supports 2.3 versions also

```
  drawable-hpi and layout-long
  drawable-large and layout
  drawable-xlarge and layout-long
```

if you feel that i have missed to understand the basic concept somewhere on the line please point out references to to elevate my  ignorance.

Comment: There're some useful information I've answered at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072382/drawables-and-layouts-for-galaxy-tab-and-motorola-xoom

Answer (score 1):

In general, these 10 inch Gingerbread tablets should have an `xlarge` screen size and a `mdpi` pixel density.