# Drawables and Layouts for Galaxy Tab and Motorola XOOM

Tags: android, resources, drawable, galaxy-tab, xoom

I'm testing my app at Galaxy Tab and Motorola XOOM emulator skins, and I can't understand, why the drawables are taken from the wrong folders. I have drawable-xhdpi folder, where I store big size pictures. However, Tab takes drawables from drawable-hdpi, and XOOM uses the drawable-mdpi folder. So, how do I manage my resources? Thanks in advance.

In addition, it feels like view sizes defined in sp are not ported properly. I have some views which need to be 80sp x 80sp, on phones with mdpi and hdpi screens they look right, but on tablets they look too small. Why can this be?

Comment: In my case, the Xoom strangely uses sw600-xhdpi resources when I am providing sw600-hdpi resources.  I'd think that because it's an mdpi device, it'd use hdpi since it's closer to its dpi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, Tab takes drawables from drawable-hdpi, and XOOM uses the drawable-mdpi folder. So, how do I manage my resources?

There is no single "Galaxy Tab" device, so I have no idea which one you are referring to there. The XOOM is an `-mdpi` device. I would expect that the Galaxy Tab 10.1 would be `-mdpi` as well. However, in the end, device manufacturers will choose values that they feel deliver the best results for existing applications.

Comment: I was talking about the P1000 model with 7" display.

Comment: @Egor: Correct, that is `-hdpi`. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/screen-geometry-fun.html

Answer (score 2):

GalaxyTab 7" use  "-large-hdpi"; XOOM 10.1" use  "-xlarge-mdpi".

check this post for details:
[GalaxyTab, Motorola Xoom Screen Desity and Size](http://situee.blogspot.com/2011/11/galaxytab-motorola-xoom-screen-desity.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have test with multiple screen resolutions and find out Android use the following qualifier for different screen resolutions:
240x320: -ldpi
320x480: -mdpi
480x800: -hdpi
GalaxyTab7.1 inches: -large
GalaxyTab10.1 inches: -xlarge

Hope this information is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Galaxy tab (the old one, running Android 2.x) is indeed not xhdpi. I had success by using the "large" qualifier to identify tablets. Else you can always use an API qualifier such as v11 for Honeycomb only resources.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the dpi qualifiers you can use screen size qualifiers instead, theres info here on exactly what tags you can use when selecting which resources to use,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

It's important to understand the difference between dpi and screen size, dpi tends to be high on phones, like a samsung galaxy s2, but on the big 10 inch tablets it tends to be low(which makes sense if you think about it, the phones squeeze more pixels into a smaller space).